# ModifyTextFileAction fails to find and replace value

Tags: install4j

We have a ModifyTextFile action:

```
     <action name="Einstellungen anpassen FR" id="59" customizedId="" beanClass="com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.text.ModifyTextFileAction" enabled="true" commentSet="true" comment="" actionElevationType="elevated" rollbackBarrier="false" rollbackBarrierExitCode="0" multiExec="false" failureStrategy="1" errorMessage="">
      <serializedBean>
        <java class="java.beans.XMLDecoder">
          <object class="com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.text.ModifyTextFileAction">
            <void property="encoding">
              <string />
            </void>
            <void property="files">
              <array class="java.io.File" length="1">
                <void index="0">
                  <object class="java.io.File">
                    <string>userstrings.txt</string>
                  </object>
                </void>
              </array>
            </void>
            <void property="replaceValue">
              <string>22357,30,2, "Paramètres_Silent"</string>
            </void>
            <void property="searchValue">
              <string>22357,30,2, "Paramètres"</string>
            </void>
          </object>
        </java>
      </serializedBean>
      <condition />
    </action>
```

The problem is that with the above action it always fails to find the text when there's an accented character such as 'è' is in the searchValue property.

The change works fine with standard Latin text, only accented chars fail.

We've tried setting multiple 'encoding' property values (1252, CP1252, Windows-1252, ISO 8859-1) but haven't had any luck.

The file itself reports in notepad++ as 'ANSI' but we can't find the exact codepage. We can't change the original codepage as it needs to remain as it is due to third-party apps reading it.

Does anyone have any idea why the replace fails to replace the value, the install log shows the following:

```
[INFO] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.text.ModifyTextFileAction [ID 59]: Execute action
   Property files: [userstrings.txt]
   Property replaceValue: 22357,30,2, "Paramètres_Silent"
   Property searchValue: 22357,30,2, "Paramètres"
   Property escapeForPropertyFile: false
   Property failIfNoReplacement: false
   Property logReplacement: true
   Property rollbackSupported: true
   Backing up C:\Program Files\test\userstrings.txt
   Execute action successful after 102 ms
```

Here's the file I'm trying to alter:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/j1bq070eznzby01/userstrings.txt?dl=0

Install4j version 7.0.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in install4j, it will be fixed in 7.0.11, please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get a build where this is already fixed.

Btw, the correct value for the "Encoding" property for your file is "Cp1252".